# Volume compare about submanifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry

When I read the volume compare theorem (first picture below), I think there should be a theorem about the boundary of ball, liking
$$
vol (\partial B_r(p)) \le vol(\partial B_r(\tilde p)) 
$$
Further, the volume of sub-manifold should can be compared. For example, the second picture can be treated as special case (n=2) of  volume compare of sub-manifold. I wonder if there is any research on this, and what is the corresponding paper?

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: You are working under assumption of a lower bound of the Ricci curvature for your assertions?

Comment: @Jfischer  Yes, there must be some bound on the curvature.  Maybe, it is Ricci curvature, sectional curvature or k-curvature. The detail is not important.